# 415 Unsupported Media Type HTTP

Tags: xml, perl, http-status-code-415

I'm trying to send a GET request to Cisco ISE, but get this error:

> 415 Unsupported Media Typen

What am I doing wrong? The API documentation says:

> Method: GET
>
> URI: https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/
>
> HTTP 'Accept' header:application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml

So, I should be able to receive data as XML.

I've already tried to do this:

```
$header->header(
    'Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.xml');
$header->header(
    'Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');
```

Nothing works.. every time I get the above error.

Here's my full code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON -support_by_pp;
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use REST::Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use HTTP::Headers;

#So dass es auch ohne SSL Sertifizierung funktioniert
BEGIN { $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0 }
#Create a user agent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts=> {
SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
verify_hostname => 0,
                                              }
                                        );

#Create a request
my $uri='https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice';
my $header = HTTP::Headers->new;
$header->header('Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $uri, $header);
$req-> authorization_basic("user", "user");

#Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);

#Check the outcome of the response
if ($res->is_success) {
  print $res->content;
} else {
   print $res->status_line, "n";
}
```

Comment: Seems like it is not agreeing on the media type.

Comment: The docs say you need an `Accept` header, but you're sending a `Content-Type`. That's the wrong header. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your documentation says you should send an `Accept` header with that long type.

> HTTP 'Accept' header:application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml

`Accept` is the content type(s) that your client will accept in the response. But you are using that as the `Content-Type` header in your GET request. This makes no sense, because a GET request has no body. Therefore, it has no content, and cannot have a type for its content.

The fact that the API responds with a 415 Unsupported Media Type is a bit strange. It could also just ignore that. We have no way to know why the developers chose to do that.

To fix your issue, change your request to use an `Accept` header instead of `Content-Type`.

```
my $header = HTTP::Headers->new;
$header->header(Accept => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $uri, $header);
```

Note you don't have to create your own HTTP::Headers object explicitly. For this simple request you can pass an array ref with key/value pairs to `HTTP::Request->new`.

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
    'GET', 
    $uri, 
    [ Accept =>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml' ],
);
```

Comment: Seems like everything is in a prominent position,  but unfortunatelly I have the same error......
Accept is not color ...do I need to install some modules?

Comment: @StayCalm can you add a dump of the request to your question please? You can do `print $req->as_string`. Just replace the basic auth data and anything else sensitive with something fake in the output before you post it here.

Comment: `GET https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice
Accept: application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice+xml
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy
`

Comment: Is that the exact same string as the documentation has @StayCalm? I think the `1.0` is missing. I didn't copy it from your doc either. :-/

Comment: I've amended the answer to use the exact same string you showed from the documentation.

Comment: @StayCalm it's always important to pay attention to details. You'll learn that over time. Sometimes it's a missing space, or a semicolon, or there's a line break to much. What I do in a case like that is copy/paste the sample data above the code I have, line them up and check if everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code

```
#Create a request
my $uri='https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $uri);

$req->header('Accept'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');

$req->authorization_basic("user", "user");

#Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

You have to send the **Accept** header not **Content-Type**.